# Pointer to array and related expression evaluation

Tags: c, optimization

An array type decays to a pointer type when it is passed to a function

That means in

```
int func(int x[*p])
```

`*p` should not be evaluated as the declaration is equivalent to `int func(int *x)`

Does the same hold for pointer to arrays?

Here is the code

```
int *p=0;
void func(int (*ptr)[*p]) //A
{
   // code
}

int main()
{
   int arr[5][5];
   func(arr);
}
```

Is evaluation of `*p` at `//A` guaranteed by the Standard?

I tried with and without optimization on g++4.6. With optimizations enabled I don't get segfault. On clang the code is not giving any segfault even without any optimizations.

Comment: Isn't declaring `void func(int (*ptr)[*p])` exactly the same as `void func(int *ptr[])`?

Comment: I had no idea that `void func(int x[RANDOM_STUFF])` was valid!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : Isn't it valid?

Answer (score 2):

From the C99 Standard Section 6.7.5.2 Array declarators, paragraph 1:

> 1. In addition to optional type qualiﬁers and the keyword static, the [
>      and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression
>      (which speciﬁes the size of an array), the expression shall have an
>      integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>      have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an
>      incomplete or function type.  The optional  type  qualiﬁers  and  the 
>      keyword static shall  appear  only  in  a declaration of a function
>      parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array
>      type derivation.

The expression `*p` evaluates to 0 and does not satisfy the requirements of the above paragraph, so the behavior is undefined.